# UBUNTU WINDOWS8

Tags: installation

Hi there i want to use 2 different operating systems on my laptop it have highly definitions but i need to know this:

i have windows 8 installed i have 1 Hard disk not divided into 2, on my laptop can i install Ubuntu side by side to windows 8 without losing data? and how.

i didn't try anything yet because i need to know if it will corrupt my windows 8 or not or i might lose data.

Comment: So you want to install Windows 8 with Ubuntu without partitioning ?

Comment: If you go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system it is explained in full

Answer (score 1):

You can boot from USB stick. Then run GParted application. Use it to shrink your Windows partition. Then install Ubuntu to the space you just freed. 
Ubuntu may offer you to do automatic installation and shrinking. If it does not, you must find Ubuntu installation guide on the language you speak well - disk partitioning is not an obvious task, and UEFI booting is even harder. You must do UEFI installation, otherwise Windows would not boot.